# Simple SSH port forward in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to create (and later close) a simple TCP port forward over SSH with Go. I'm new to Golang and statically typed languages. (Coming from Ruby.)

In a terminal I would simply run `ssh -L 9000:localhost:9999 user@server.com` and this accomplishes what I need. I want to do the same, programmatically with Go.

I have tried using [this example](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh#example-ClientConn-Listen) as a starting point and [this recent test](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/ssh/test/forward_test.go?spec=svn.crypto.40246d2ae2eb433547e5856182aa8242675b3bfb&repo=crypto&name=40246d2ae2eb&r=40246d2ae2eb433547e5856182aa8242675b3bfb) to try to understand what to do, but now I have a pile of confusing jumbled code when it seems like this is actually a very simple thing to do.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: What is the pile of jumbled code that you do have?

Comment: Thanks MichaelT, the jumbled pile was successfully deleted and recreated in to the below answer. Thanks for your desire to help!

Comment: Do you think that (in your answer below) you could go through the steps of what it took to get to the final code, what the root cause was and how it was resolved?

Comment: I hope those edits help. There was so much changed and changed again, it's hard to layout how I got there. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 22):

I finally figured out how to do this, I got hints from schmichael in an IRC channel. Thanks to all!

EDIT: A little explanation:
A big part of the problem I was having was that I did not realize a local `net.Listener` (not just a local `net.Conn`) needed setup to receive a local request and create the `net.Conn` before forwarding the bytes.
Also, there exist both port forwards and reverse port forwards and I hadn't previously thought in detail about the fact that a regular port forward also sends bytes back, so copying the remote reader to local writer was not something I had implemented, yet it's very much needed.
Here is an attempt to relate the essence of what this code does:

- Listen on local port 9000.
- Upon attempted read from local port 9000: (`listener.Accept()`),
- Accept connection and return a local `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` and,
- Connect to remote server and,
- Connect to remote port 9999 returning a `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`.
- Continually copy local `io.Reader` bytes to remote `io.Writer`,
- Continually copy remote `io.Reader` bytes to local `io.Writer`.

Here is the code:

```
package main

// Forward from local port 9000 to remote port 9999

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

var (
    username         = "root"
    password         = "password"
    serverAddrString = "192.168.1.100:22"
    localAddrString  = "localhost:9000"
    remoteAddrString = "localhost:9999"
)

func forward(localConn net.Conn, config *ssh.ClientConfig) {
    // Setup sshClientConn (type *ssh.ClientConn)
    sshClientConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", serverAddrString, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ssh.Dial failed: %s", err)
    }

    // Setup sshConn (type net.Conn)
    sshConn, err := sshClientConn.Dial("tcp", remoteAddrString)

    // Copy localConn.Reader to sshConn.Writer
    go func() {
        _, err = io.Copy(sshConn, localConn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("io.Copy failed: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    // Copy sshConn.Reader to localConn.Writer
    go func() {
        _, err = io.Copy(localConn, sshConn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("io.Copy failed: %v", err)
        }
    }()
}

func main() {
    // Setup SSH config (type *ssh.ClientConfig)
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: username,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(password),
        },
    }

    // Setup localListener (type net.Listener)
    localListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", localAddrString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("net.Listen failed: %v", err)
    }

    for {
        // Setup localConn (type net.Conn)
        localConn, err := localListener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("listen.Accept failed: %v", err)
        }
        go forward(localConn, config)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make dynamic forwarding work? like ssh -D

Comment: I wish I could help you there friend, but I'm not familiar enough with SOCKS and all. [This](https://github.com/shouxi/goproxy/blob/master/goproxy_socks5_v0.01.go) might help you though. Good luck, let me know if you get it!

Comment: Just a note - the `go.grypto` package is now hosted at         `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`, plus in order to get this excellent example to work (thank you @damick!), you need to look into swapping `ssh.ClientAuth` with `ssh.AuthMethod`, as per the changes to the package API.

Answer (score 5):

I have used your (damick) example code to build a tiny open source tool: **SSHTunnel**
https://github.com/SommerEngineering/SSHTunnel

Therefore, the code is freely available at GitHub for anyone: Please feel free to use it for learning purposes or for anything else :) I have mentioned your nickname and also linked to this question.

Best regards,
Thorsten.

Answer (score 2):

I'v finished a simple SSH port forward tool called [mallory](https://github.com/justmao945/mallory).
It provides HTTP proxy instead of SOCKS proxy, which is really similar to `ssh -D`.

The core code is similar to damick's answer.

1. Create ClientConfig
2. `ssh.Dial` to remote SSH server with the config and return `Client`
3. Now you can use `Client.Dial` to *forward* anything you like.

> Dial initiates a connection to the addr from the remote host. The resulting connection has a zero LocalAddr() and RemoteAddr().
>
> If you want to serve a SOCKS proxy server, use `Client.Dial` to connect to the remote server.

Comment: I have successfully installed mallory, but when I run the command:mallory -engine=ssh -remote=ssh://root:123456789abc@104.207.140.29:22, I have encountered the below error:

flag provided but not defined: -engine Usage of mallory: -config string config file (default "$HOME/.config/mallory.json") -reload send signal to reload config file -suffix string print pulbic suffix for the given domain

Comment: hope the help from you

Comment: Can  i connect  with user and password. Thank

Answer (score 0):

I Wrote a tool,Called gosshtool,with this tool,you can easy to create a simple TCP port forward over SSH with Go.https://github.com/scottkiss/gosshtool

I use this tool implemented a port forward server example project:
https://github.com/scottkiss/gooverssh