# How can I create a socks5 tunnel with Go's ssh package?

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

While I understand Go, I don't quite understand what the following command does in `ssh` terminology:

```
ssh -N -C -D 8888 user@host.com
```

Doing this allows me to provide `127.0.0.1:8888` as a socks5 proxy to applications that support proxying.

This is not about port forwarding like other existing questions; this is about dynamic port forwarding.

How can I do a similar thing with [Go's ssh package](http://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)? I am trying to create a tunnel to bypass censorship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple SSH port forward in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417223/simple-ssh-port-forward-in-golang)

Comment: It looks like Go's `ssh` package does not support that.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the command below ?

`ssh -D 8888 -N -q user@host`