# How do I do mongodump on a server and transfer that to my local machine using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, ssh, portforwarding, mgo

I wrote a go program ( which is basically the code in this example, [Simple SSH port forward in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417223/simple-ssh-port-forward-in-golang) )  that connects to a remote  mongodb server by creating an ssh tunnel. I can query the server using mgo api. Now, instead of querying the server everytime, I want to copy a few collections of the database to my local machine and query locally. It is important to note that I cannot copy it directly to my local machine as there is port forwarding involved. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why not use `scp` or `sftp` to transfer the `mongodump` files from the remote server to local directly?

Comment: I want to automate that process using go program. So my go prog, when installed, has to connect to the remote server and do the mongodump and bring it to the local machine and create a database here

Comment: I'm confused, let me try to get this straight. You wrote a go program that can connect to a remote MongoDB server using SSH tunnel. Now you want that same program to copy some collections to your local database and query the local database instead. Is this what you want?

Comment: @kevin yes,exactly

Comment: You would have to connect to the two MongoDB servers, query from the remote, and insert into the local. Drop the local databases first if required. Once the local database is populated, do further queries from the local database. Optionally disconnect from the remote database. However, as the answer below pointed out, this may not be the best thing to do, since your code is now doing two different things simultaneously, which could be hard to maintain. However if you're happy to maintain it, the method I described above *could* work.

Answer (score 3):

You are reinventing the wheel. Use cron to create an ssh tunnel to the destination and then use a local mongodump to connect against your local tunnel endpoint

```
ssh -f user@mongodb.example.com -L 27017:mongodb.example.com:27017 -N
mongodump localhost:27017 <your opts here>
```

Comment: what you are suggesting is creating the tunnel and doing mongodump MANUALLY. I am trying to automate that using golang so that if a user runs that golang code, it should get the job done and the user need not fire those commands. 

To make it clear, how can I do what you suggested using golang ?

Comment: As said: use those two lines of code. Add them to a shell script, if you must. If you really want to do it in Go, have a look at [the sources of `mongodump`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/tree/master/mongodump). Quite complex, hence there is no simple answer to your question.